# Best Text Styles in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Where can i get good and clean CSS for text.

For ex.The word press font and the text looks amazing !!

Any example or any website for making such ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Georgia is nice. Unfortunately, web devs are limited to the core 10-12 fonts that are included in most OS's and supported by most browsers. If you want nice fonts for headings or small pieces of text then use Cufon but dont put big blocks of text through this as it wont be selectable. So i'm afraid your lumped with the basic fonts: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Palatino, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Typechart is a great tool. Take a look, you can grab the CSS http://www.typechart.com/

Answer (score 0):

While not exclusively for text (more design in general), [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) is always a great place for ideas, etc.